# Merging values from a dataframe after filtering the values by the last date

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 dataframes:

`df_1`

```
product_id      qty_received    date_received
a_1             62              2021-06-11
a_2             30              2021-06-11
a_3             30              2021-06-11
a_4             1               2021-05-24
a_5             1               2021-05-24
a_1             20              2021-05-23  # repeating product_id
```

`df_2`

```
product_id
a_1
b_2
c_4
a_3
a_5
e_5
```

I am trying to join `qty_received` and the last `date_received` from `df_1` to `df_2` so that the result look like this:

```
product_id      last_receive    qty_received
a_1             2021-06-11      62
b_2             No information  0
c_4             No information  0
a_3             2021-06-11      30
a_5             2021-05-24      1
e_5             No information  0
```

What I've tried:

```
df_2.merge(df_1, on='product_id', how='left')
```

But this increases the total row count for some reason, I understand that it might create new rows because there are more than one of the same `product_id` in `df_1` but not in `df_2`.

Then I tried grouping it and taking the `max` `date_received`:

```
df_1.groupby(['product_id'])['date_received', 'qty_received'].max().reset_index()
```

But this returns both the max `date_received` and `qty_received`, rather then the `qty_received` of the `max` `date_received`.

How can I filter out the max `date_received` and get `product_id` `qty_received` of that date? And what if I wanted to have the last 2 dates so that I would have 2 more columns `second_last_received` and `second_qty_received` of the second-highest `date_received` of each product?
So that the result would be:

```
product_id      last_receive    qty_received        second_last_receive    second_qty_received
a_1             2021-06-11      62                  2021-05-23             20
b_2             No information  0                   No information         No information 
c_4             No information  0                   No information         No information 
a_3             2021-06-11      30                  No information         No information 
a_5             2021-05-24      1                   No information         No information 
e_5             No information  0                   No information         No information
```

Comment: You need only last and last previous rows?

Comment: I would need 2 last dates with the corresponding `qty_received`.

Comment: Sure, so another should be removed? If there are 3rd, 4th...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
#converted values to datetimes
df_1['date_received'] = pd.to_datetime(df_1['date_received'])
#sorting per date_received
df = df_1.sort_values(by="date_received", ascending=False)
#created counter column per product_id (already sorted, so by descending dates)
df['g'] = df.groupby(['product_id'])['date_received'].cumcount()

#filter last and last previous only rows
df = df[df['g'] < 2]

#dict for rename MultiIndex levels from counter
d = {0:'last', 1:'second_last'}
#rehape by unstack, sorting by second level
df = df.set_index(['product_id','g']).unstack().sort_index(axis=1,level=1).rename(columns=d)
#flatten MutiIndex
df.columns = df.columns.map(lambda x: f'{x[1]}_{x[0]}')
#joined df_2 and repalaced NaNs
df = df_2.join(df, on='product_id').fillna({'last_qty_received':0}).fillna("No information")
```

---

```
print (df)
  product_id   last_date_received  last_qty_received  \
0        a_1  2021-06-11 00:00:00               62.0   
1        b_2       No information                0.0   
2        c_4       No information                0.0   
3        a_3  2021-06-11 00:00:00               30.0   
4        a_5  2021-05-24 00:00:00                1.0   
5        e_5       No information                0.0   

  second_last_date_received second_last_qty_received  
0       2021-05-23 00:00:00                     20.0  
1            No information           No information  
2            No information           No information  
3            No information           No information  
4            No information           No information  
5            No information           No information
```

Comment: I get a `ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected 637 rows, received array of length 764` at `df= df.set_index(['product_id',g.replace(d)]).unstack()`, any idea why could it happen?

Comment: @JonasPalačionis - I change answer for create `g` column, maybe this should help. Honestly not idea.

Comment: Could you take a look a this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68376968/joining-two-multiindex-pivoted-dataframes?noredirect=1#comment120844601_68376968)

Answer (score 1):

You can use groupby with idxmax:

**Sample data:**

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'product_id': {0: 'a_1', 1: 'a_2', 2: 'a_3', 3: 'a_4', 4: 'a_5', 5: 'a_1'},
 'qty_received': {0: 62, 1: 30, 2: 30, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 20},
 'date_received': {0: '2021-06-11',
  1: '2021-06-11',
  2: '2021-06-11',
  3: '2021-05-24',
  4: '2021-05-24',
  5: '2021-05-23'}})
df1['date_received'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['date_received'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'product_id': {0: 'a_1', 1: 'b_2', 2: 'c_4', 3: 'a_3', 4: 'a_5', 5: 'e_5'}})
```

**Code:**

```
df1 = df1.loc[df1.groupby(['product_id'])['date_received'].idxmax()].set_index('product_id')
df2.set_index('product_id').join(df1)
```

**Output:**

```
            qty_received date_received
product_id                            
a_1                 62.0    2021-06-11
b_2                  NaN           NaT
c_4                  NaN           NaT
a_3                 30.0    2021-06-11
a_5                  1.0    2021-05-24
e_5                  NaN           NaT
```

**Second Question, what if there are more dates to consider:**

Then you can use: `.rank()` like this:

```
df1['rank'] = df1.groupby(['product_id'])['date_received'].rank(method='max', ascending=False)
df1 = df1.pivot(index='product_id', columns='rank').swaplevel(axis=1).sort_index(axis=1,level=[0,1],ascending=[True,False])
df2.set_index('product_id').join(df1)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would sort the values in df1 by the date recieved, then drop duplicate product_ids and keep the last value:

```
df1_temp = df1.sort_values(by="date_received").drop_duplicates("product_id", keep="last")

  product_id  qty_received date_received
3        a_4             1    2021-05-24
4        a_5             1    2021-05-24
0        a_1            62    2021-06-11
1        a_2            30    2021-06-11
2        a_3            30    2021-06-11
```

Then you can use your merge code without issues:

```
df2_merged = df_2.merge(df1_temp, on='product_id', how='left')
df2_merged["qtr_received"].fillna(0, inplace=True)
df2_merged["date_received"].fillna("No information", inplace=True)

output:
  product_id  qty_received   date_received
0        a_1          62.0      2021-06-11
1        b_2           0.0  No information
2        c_4           0.0  No information
3        a_3          30.0      2021-06-11
4        a_5           1.0      2021-05-24
5        e_5           0.0  No information
```

to get the items from the first dataframe which are not the last recieved use:

```
not_last = df1[~df1.isin(df1_temp)].dropna()
```

then follow a similar procedure to sort by date and drop duplicates:

```
second_last = second_recieved.sort_values(by="date_received").drop_duplicates("product_id", keep="last")
```

merge the dataframes again:

```
df2_second_merge = df_2.merge(second_last, on='product_id', how='left')
```

Then join the two dataframes:

```
df2_new.join(df2_second_merge.set_index("product_id"), on ="product_id", rsuffix="_second")
```

This could be wrapped up in a function, to do any number of levels. However I will leave this to you if required

Comment: But this eliminates the possibility to have the `second_last_date_received` which I would like to have.