# Joining two multiindex pivoted dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have two daframes with multiindexes:

`df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(df1).set_index(['group','category'])`

```
df1 = {('group', ''): {0: 'A',
  1: 'A',
  2: 'A',
  3: 'A',
  4: 'A',
  5: 'A',
  6: 'A',
  7: 'A',
  8: 'A',
  9: 'B',
  10: 'B',
  11: 'B',
  12: 'B',
  13: 'B',
  14: 'B',
  15: 'B',
  16: 'B',
  17: 'B',
  18: 'C',
  19: 'C',
  20: 'C',
  21: 'C',
  22: 'C',
  23: 'C',
  24: 'C',
  25: 'C',
  26: 'D',
  27: 'D',
  28: 'D',
  29: 'D',
  30: 'D',
  31: 'D',
  32: 'D'},
 ('category', ''): {0: 'Google',
  1: 'Apple',
  2: 'Amazon',
  3: 'Not used',
  4: 'Facebook',
  5: 'Tesla',
  6: 'Netflix',
  7: 'Uber',
  8: 'total',
  9: 'Google',
  10: 'Apple',
  11: 'Amazon',
  12: 'Not used',
  13: 'Facebook',
  14: 'Tesla',
  15: 'Netflix',
  16: 'Uber',
  17: 'total',
  18: 'Google',
  19: 'Apple',
  20: 'Amazon',
  21: 'Facebook',
  22: 'Tesla',
  23: 'Netflix',
  24: 'Uber',
  25: 'total',
  26: 'Google',
  27: 'Apple',
  28: 'Amazon',
  29: 'Facebook',
  30: 'Netflix',
  31: 'Uber',
  32: 'total'},
 (pd.Timestamp('2021-06-28 00:00:00'), 'total_orders'): {0: 88.0,
  1: 67.0,
  2: 191.0,
  3: 71.0,
  4: 563.0,
  5: 12.0,
  6: 4.0,
  7: 57.0,
  8: 1053.0,
  9: 90.0,
  10: 26.0,
  11: 49.0,
  12: 3.0,
  13: 250.0,
  14: 7.0,
  15: 2.0,
  16: 44.0,
  17: 471.0,
  18: 36.0,
  19: 52.0,
  20: 97.0,
  21: 754.0,
  22: 10.0,
  23: 0.0,
  24: 52.0,
  25: 1001.0,
  26: 16.0,
  27: 22.0,
  28: 5.0,
  29: 57.0,
  30: 3.0,
  31: 33.0,
  32: 136.0},
 (pd.Timestamp('2021-06-28 00:00:00'), 'total_sales'): {0: 6275.8099999999995,
  1: 39644.46,
  2: 102204.87999999999,
  3: 386.0,
  4: 152139.33999999997,
  5: 831.22,
  6: 1545.71,
  7: 35658.39,
  8: 338685.81,
  9: 6524.44,
  10: 7992.75,
  11: 15163.740000000002,
  12: 94.0,
  13: 84499.20999999999,
  14: 1408.3,
  15: 329.0,
  16: 34099.149999999994,
  17: 150110.58999999997,
  18: 3330.8899999999994,
  19: 21592.699999999997,
  20: 33013.270000000004,
  21: 153828.77999999994,
  22: 683.0,
  23: 0.0,
  24: 38221.569999999985,
  25: 250670.20999999993,
  26: 2852.4900000000002,
  27: 10873.1,
  28: 3389.0,
  29: 9223.810000000001,
  30: 1249.0,
  31: 30186.33,
  32: 57773.73},
 (pd.Timestamp('2021-07-05 00:00:00'), 'total_orders'): {0: 109.0,
  1: 48.0,
  2: 175.0,
  3: 101.0,
  4: 597.0,
  5: 13.0,
  6: 5.0,
  7: 44.0,
  8: 1092.0,
  9: 62.0,
  10: 13.0,
  11: 37.0,
  12: 6.0,
  13: 196.0,
  14: 8.0,
  15: 1.0,
  16: 33.0,
  17: 356.0,
  18: 77.0,
  19: 51.0,
  20: 154.0,
  21: 900.0,
  22: 9.0,
  23: 2.0,
  24: 88.0,
  25: 1281.0,
  26: 1.0,
  27: 20.0,
  28: 23.0,
  29: 83.0,
  30: 0.0,
  31: 29.0,
  32: 156.0},
 (pd.Timestamp('2021-07-05 00:00:00'), 'total_sales'): {0: 4671.62,
  1: 30085.13,
  2: 98651.67999999998,
  3: 139.1,
  4: 189059.11000000002,
  5: 2453.0,
  6: 1914.6000000000001,
  7: 28252.86,
  8: 355227.1,
  9: 6532.189999999999,
  10: 6865.1,
  11: 11887.870000000003,
  12: 10.0,
  13: 45041.29,
  14: 741.0,
  15: 448.61,
  16: 29840.199999999997,
  17: 101366.26000000001,
  18: 5992.149999999999,
  19: 22293.859999999997,
  20: 59548.37999999999,
  21: 167868.84000000005,
  22: 1115.0,
  23: 1048.0,
  24: 78905.86,
  25: 336772.09,
  26: 53.0,
  27: 14942.22,
  28: 9245.560000000001,
  29: 24805.600000000002,
  30: 0.0,
  31: 35821.740000000005,
  32: 84868.12000000001},
 (pd.Timestamp('2021-07-12 00:00:00'), 'total_orders'): {0: 23.0,
  1: 12.0,
  2: 42.0,
  3: 0.0,
  4: 111.0,
  5: 2.0,
  6: 0.0,
  7: 10.0,
  8: 200.0,
  9: 0.0,
  10: 0.0,
  11: 0.0,
  12: 0.0,
  13: 0.0,
  14: 0.0,
  15: 0.0,
  16: 0.0,
  17: 0.0,
  18: 10.0,
  19: 5.0,
  20: 18.0,
  21: 113.0,
  22: 0.0,
  23: 0.0,
  24: 7.0,
  25: 153.0,
  26: 6.0,
  27: 3.0,
  28: 3.0,
  29: 12.0,
  30: 0.0,
  31: 4.0,
  32: 28.0},
 (pd.Timestamp('2021-07-12 00:00:00'), 'total_sales'): {0: 881.4,
  1: 3195.1,
  2: 12049.1,
  3: 0.0,
  4: 16679.64,
  5: 178.0,
  6: 0.0,
  7: 5427.7,
  8: 38410.939999999995,
  9: 0.0,
  10: 0.0,
  11: 0.0,
  12: 0.0,
  13: 0.0,
  14: 0.0,
  15: 0.0,
  16: 0.0,
  17: 0.0,
  18: 936.69,
  19: 2875.21,
  20: 7828.210000000001,
  21: 19104.300000000003,
  22: 0.0,
  23: 0.0,
  24: 5063.0,
  25: 35807.41,
  26: 1017.05,
  27: 1443.1,
  28: 1237.01,
  29: 2472.0,
  30: 0.0,
  31: 2516.1,
  32: 8685.26}}
```

`df1`

```
                created_at          2021-06-28                  2021-07-05                  2021-07-12 
                                    total_orders    total_sales total_orders    total_sales total_orders    total_sales  
Group           category                        
A               Google              88.00           5,215.81    102.00          3,511.52    23.00           881.30
                Facebook            51.00           32,533.35   38.00           30,085.13   12.00           3,125.10
                Apple               121.00          102,203.88  115.00          28,551.58   32.00           12,032.10
                Amazon              553.00          152,132.33  521.00          182,052.11  111.00          15,512.53
                Tesla               12.00           831.22      13.00           2,353.00    2.00            118.00
                Uber                3.00            1,535.11    5.00            1,213.50    0.00            0.00
                Netflix             51.00           35,558.32   33.00           28,252.85   10.00           5,321.10
                total               1,053.00        338,585.81  1,022.00        355,221.10  200.00          38,310.23
B               Google              20.00           5,523.33    52.00           5,532.12    0.00            0.00            
                Facebook            25.00           1,222.15    13.00           5,855.10    0.00            0.00
                Apple               32.00           15,153.13   31.00           11,881.81   0.00            0.00
                Amazon              250.00          83,322.21   125.00          35,031.22   0.00            0.00
                Tesla               1.0 0           1,308.30    8.00            131.00      0.00            0.00
                Uber                2.00            322.00      1.00            338.51      0.00            0.00
                Netflix             33.00           33,022.15   33.00           22,830.20   0.00            0.00
                total               311.00          150,110.52  355.00          101,355.25  0.00            0.00
C               Google              35.00           3,330.82    11.00           5,222.15    10.00           235.52         
                Facebook            52.00           21,522.10   51.00           22,223.85   5.00            2,815.21
                Apple               21.00           33,013.21   153.00          52,538.38   18.00           1,828.21
                Amazon              153.00          153,828.18  200.00          151,858.83  113.00          12,103.30
                Tesla               10.00           583.00      2.00            1,115.00    0.00            0.00
                Uber                0.00            0.00        2.00            1,038.00    0.00            0.00
                Netflix             52.00           38,221.51   88.00           18,205.85   1.00            5,053.00
                total               1,001.00        250,510.21  1,281.00        335,112.02  153.00          35,801.31
D               Google              15.00           2,852.32    1.00            53.00       5.00            1,011.05        
                Facebook            22.00           10,813.10   20.00           13,232.22   3.00            1,333.10
                Apple               5.0             3,382.00    23.00           2,235.55    3.00            1,231.01
                Amazon              51.00           2,223.81    83.00           23,805.50   12.00           2,312.00
                Uber                3.0 0           1,232.00    0.00            0.00        0.00            0.00
                Netflix             33.00           30,185.33   22.00           35,821.13   3.00            2,515.10
                total               135.00          51,113.13   155.00          83,858.12   28.00           8,585.25
```

`df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(df2).set_index(['group / category'])`

```
d = {'group / category': {0: 'Total',
  1: 'A',
  2: 'B',
  3: 'C',
  4: 'D',
  5: 'Apple',
  6: 'A',
  7: 'B',
  8: 'C',
  9: 'D',
  10: 'Amazon',
  11: 'A',
  12: 'B',
  13: 'C',
  14: 'D',
  15: 'Netflix',
  16: 'A',
  17: 'B',
  18: 'C',
  19: 'D',
  20: 'Facebook',
  21: 'A',
  22: 'B',
  23: 'C',
  24: 'D',
  25: 'Tesla',
  26: 'A',
  27: 'B',
  28: 'C',
  29: 'D',
  30: 'Uber',
  31: 'A',
  32: 'B',
  33: 'C',
  34: 'D',
  35: 'Google',
  36: 'A',
  37: 'B',
  38: 'C',
  39: 'D'},
 '': {0: 'Total',
  1: 'Totals by Channel',
  2: np.nan,
  3: np.nan,
  4: np.nan,
  5: 'Total Apple',
  6: 'Apple By Channel',
  7: np.nan,
  8: np.nan,
  9: np.nan,
  10: 'Total Amazon',
  11: 'Amazon by Channel',
  12: np.nan,
  13: np.nan,
  14: np.nan,
  15: 'Total Netflix',
  16: 'Netflix by Channel',
  17: np.nan,
  18: np.nan,
  19: np.nan,
  20: 'Total Facebook',
  21: 'Facebook by Channel',
  22: np.nan,
  23: np.nan,
  24: np.nan,
  25: 'Total Tesla',
  26: 'Tesla by Channel',
  27: np.nan,
  28: np.nan,
  29: np.nan,
  30: 'Total Uber',
  31: 'Uber by Channel',
  32: np.nan,
  33: np.nan,
  34: np.nan,
  35: 'Total Google',
  36: 'Google by Channel',
  37: np.nan,
  38: np.nan,
  39: np.nan},
 1: {0: 607.5277641202152,
  1: 221.50082266792856,
  2: 64.460440147,
  3: 265.1530371974946,
  4: 56.413464107792045,
  5: 177.48074540313092,
  6: 52.172,
  7: 20.9447844,
  8: 83.55718929717925,
  9: 20.806771705951697,
  10: 178.3766353690825,
  11: 52.425508769690694,
  12: 17.88071596,
  13: 91.10086982794643,
  14: 16.969540811445366,
  15: 128.8795397517309,
  16: 53.52039700062155,
  17: 12.1243325,
  18: 55.94068246571674,
  19: 7.294127785392621,
  20: 69.07807089184563,
  21: 28.300470581874837,
  22: 5.810764652,
  23: 25.475930745418292,
  24: 9.490904912552498,
  25: 8.184780211399392,
  26: 6.807138946302334,
  27: 0.869207661,
  28: 0.5084336040970575,
  29: 0,
  30: 9.293956915067886,
  31: 6.384936971649232,
  32: 0.913782413,
  33: 1.5322078073061867,
  34: 0.4630297231124678,
  35: 36.23403557795798,
  36: 21.890370397789923,
  37: 5.916852561,
  38: 7.03772344983066,
  39: 1.3890891693374032},
 2: {0: 635.4690491915759,
  1: 231.4573181155924,
  2: 67.481716829,
  3: 277.5807099999998,
  4: 58.949304246983736,
  5: 185.65887577993723,
  6: 54.517,
  7: 21.92632044,
  8: 87.47349898707688,
  9: 21.742056352860352,
  10: 186.6038963173654,
  11: 54.7820864335212,
  12: 18.71872129,
  13: 95.37075040035738,
  14: 17.73233819348684,
  15: 134.80302342121337,
  16: 55.926190956481534,
  17: 12.69221484,
  18: 58.56261169338368,
  19: 7.622005931348156,
  20: 72.24367956241771,
  21: 29.5726042895728,
  22: 6.083562133,
  23: 26.66998281055652,
  24: 9.917530329288393,
  25: 8.555606693927,
  26: 7.113126469779095,
  27: 0.910216433,
  28: 0.5322637911479053,
  29: 0.0,
  30: 9.716385738295367,
  31: 6.671946105284065,
  32: 0.956574175,
  33: 1.6040220980113027,
  34: 0.4838433599999999,
  35: 37.88758167841983,
  36: 22.874363860953647,
  37: 6.194107518,
  38: 7.367580219466185,
  39: 1.4515300799999995},
 3: {0: 607.2971827405001,
  1: 221.26749278974862,
  2: 64.471138092,
  3: 265.2044999999998,
  4: 56.354051858751745,
  5: 177.42361595891452,
  6: 52.117,
  7: 20.94835038,
  8: 83.57340667555117,
  9: 20.784858903363354,
  10: 178.323907459086,
  11: 52.37029646474982,
  12: 17.88339044,
  13: 91.11855133792106,
  14: 16.95166921641509,
  15: 128.82813286243115,
  16: 53.46403160619618,
  17: 12.1261155,
  18: 55.95153983444301,
  19: 7.286445921791947,
  20: 69.04410667683521,
  21: 28.270665735943805,
  22: 5.811656147,
  23: 25.480875296710053,
  24: 9.480909497181356,
  25: 8.178601399067174,
  26: 6.7999699585309585,
  27: 0.870099156,
  28: 0.5085322845362154,
  29: 0.0,
  30: 9.287042311133577,
  31: 6.378212628950804,
  32: 0.913782413,
  33: 1.5325051891827732,
  34: 0.4625420799999998,
  35: 36.21177607303267,
  36: 21.86731639537707,
  37: 5.917744056,
  38: 7.039089381655591,
  39: 1.3876262399999995}}
```

```
                                    Total               1           2               3
Group / Category                
TOTAL                               Total               501.53      535.31          501.30
A                                   Totals by Group     221.50      231.35          221.21
B                                   NaN                 53.35       51.38           53.31
C                                   NaN                 255.15      211.58          255.20
D                                   NaN                 55.31       58.25           55.35
Google                              Total Google        111.38      185.55          111.32
A                                   Google By Group     52.11       53.52           52.12
B                                   NaN                 20.23       21.23           20.25
C                                   NaN                 83.55       81.31           83.51
D                                   NaN                 20.81       21.13           20.18
Facebook                            Total Facebook      118.38      185.50          118.32
A                                   Facebook by Group   52.33       53.18           52.31
B                                   NaN                 11.88       18.12           11.88
C                                   NaN                 21.10       25.31           21.12
D                                   NaN                 15.21       11.13           15.25
Apple                               Total Apple         128.88      133.80          128.83
A                                   Apple by Group      53.52       55.23           53.35
B                                   NaN                 12.12       12.52           12.13
C                                   NaN                 55.23       58.55           55.25
D                                   NaN                 1.22        1.52            1.22
Amazon                              Total Amazon        52.08       12.23           52.03
A                                   Amazon by Group     28.30       22.51           28.21
B                                   NaN                 5.81        5.08            5.81
C                                   NaN                 25.38       25.51           25.38
D                                   NaN                 2.32        2.22            2.38
Tesla                               Total Tesla         8.18        8.55            8.18
A                                   Tesla by Group      5.81        1.11            5.80
B                                   NaN                 0.81        0.21            0.81
C                                   NaN                 0.51        0.53            0.51
D                                   NaN                 0.00        0.00            0.00
Uber                                Total Uber          2.22        2.12            2.22
A                                   Uber by Group       5.38        5.51            5.38
B                                   NaN                 0.21        0.25            0.21
C                                   NaN                 1.53        1.50            1.53
D                                   NaN                 0.35        0.38            0.35
Netflix                             Total Netflix       35.23       31.82           35.21
A                                   Netflix by Group    21.82       22.81           21.81
B                                   NaN                 5.22        5.12            5.22
C                                   NaN                 1.03        1.31            1.03
D                                   NaN                 1.32        1.35            1.32
```

The output should look like this:

```
                created_at          2021-06-28                                  2021-07-05                              2021-07-12 
                                    total_orders    total_sales   df2-1         total_orders    total_sales     df2-2   total_orders    total_sales         df2-3
Group           category                                          501.53                                        ...                                         ...
A               Google              88.00           5,215.81      52.11         102.00          3,511.52                23.00           881.30
                Facebook            51.00           32,533.35     52.33         38.00           30,085.13               12.00           3,125.10
                Apple               121.00          102,203.88    53.52         115.00          28,551.58               32.00           12,032.10
                Amazon              553.00          152,132.33    28.30         521.00          182,052.11              111.00          15,512.53
                Tesla               12.00           831.22        5.81          13.00           2,353.00                2.00            118.00
                Uber                3.00            1,535.11      5.38          5.00            1,213.50                0.00            0.00
                Netflix             51.00           35,558.32     21.82         33.00           28,252.85               10.00           5,321.10
                total               1,053.00        338,585.81    221.50        1,022.00        355,221.10              200.00          38,310.23
B               Google              20.00           5,523.33      20.23         52.00           5,532.12                0.00            0.00            
                Facebook            25.00           1,222.15      11.88         13.00           5,855.10                0.00            0.00
                Apple               32.00           15,153.13     12.12         31.00           11,881.81               0.00            0.00
                Amazon              250.00          83,322.21     5.81          125.00          35,031.22               0.00            0.00
                Tesla               1.0 0           1,308.30      0.81          8.00            131.00                  0.00            0.00
                Uber                2.00            322.00        0.21          1.00            338.51                  0.00            0.00
                Netflix             33.00           33,022.15     5.22          33.00           22,830.20               0.00            0.00
                total               311.00          150,110.52    53.35         355.00          101,355.25              0.00            0.00
C               Google              35.00           3,330.82      83.55         11.00           5,222.15                10.00           235.52         
                Facebook            52.00           21,522.10     21.10         51.00           22,223.85               5.00            2,815.21
                Apple               21.00           33,013.21     55.23         153.00          52,538.38               18.00           1,828.21
                Amazon              153.00          153,828.18    25.38         200.00          151,858.83              113.00          12,103.30
                Tesla               10.00           583.00        0.51          2.00            1,115.00                0.00            0.00
                Uber                0.00            0.00          1.53          2.00            1,038.00                0.00            0.00
                Netflix             52.00           38,221.51     1.03          88.00           18,205.85               1.00            5,053.00
                total               1,001.00        250,510.21    255.15        1,281.00        335,112.02              153.00          35,801.31
D               Google              15.00           2,852.32      20.81         1.00            53.00                   5.00            1,011.05        
                Facebook            22.00           10,813.10     15.21         20.00           13,232.22               3.00            1,333.10
                Apple               5.0             3,382.00      1.22          23.00           2,235.55                3.00            1,231.01
                Amazon              51.00           2,223.81      2.32          83.00           23,805.50               12.00           2,312.00
                Uber                3.0 0           1,232.00      0.35          0.00            0.00                    0.00            0.00
                Netflix             33.00           30,185.33     1.32          22.00           35,821.13               3.00            2,515.10
                total               135.00          51,113.13     55.31         155.00          83,858.12               28.00           8,585.25
```

The goal is to add columns `1, 2, 3` from `df2` to `df1` on matching `groups` and `categories` and the `created_at` in `df1` correspond to `1, 2, 3` in `df2` like so:
`2021-06-28 == 1, 2021-07-05 == 2,  2021-07-12  == 3`, basically noting the first, second and third weeks of July.

So in total I have `4 groups` and `7 categories` which has a nice structure in `df1` but they are in the same column in `df2` and the column `total` in `df2` is not useful as I need to map the column `Group / Category` after splitting it to `groups = A, B, C, D` and `categories = Google, Facebook, Apple, Amazon, Tesla, Uber, Netflix`.

I, unfortunately, have no clue how I could achieve this.

Comment: Multi-Index DataFrames are generally difficult to recreate from plaintext outputs. Could you add some DataFrame constructors `df1 = pd.DataFrame(....)` what can be used to easily build samples of these frames?

Comment: Is there a module or a way to have a dataframe exported in an `pd.DataFrame(...)`  format for copy - pasting procedures?

Comment: `df1.to_dict()` is close, but double check that the frame build from it is correct.

Comment: As the keys are the same for `categories` the `dataframe` ends up being built with only the last of the `7` category values instead of 7 categories.

Comment: Then `reset_index` call `to_dict` then do a constructor like `pd.DataFrame(dict_from_output).set_index([index_cols...])`

Comment: You could provide an empty DataFrame declaration with the index and columns only, and a separate one for the records (possibly as a list). And perhaps restrict it to 10 rows per df. If you're able to re-create the sample correctly on your machine then you can post that here, so we can copy-paste to create the initial data. Btw, you should add what code you've tried so far which doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you for the tips, added constructrors.

Comment: Updated the code a bit.